# PDOException : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142

Tags: 7

I meet a error when I cleaned the cache or I run an update. It blocks my website, do you have a solution ? thank you

[image]

Comment: _DROP command denied to user 'administrateur'_ seems pretty clear?

Comment: yes but why it strikes me this message? before that worked fine

Comment: In that case it's as simple a: _something changed_ :) Not something that's guessable from here, you'd need to ask your server admin why permissions were changed

Comment: I'm the admin :( I uninstalled the module "boost", it can be changed to drupal

Comment: Maybe you've upgraded something and it's changed mySQL config at the same time? DROP is always required for a db-based cache clear, so if it was working previously, it means something in mysql perms has been changed

Comment: I still do not see the problem. Must be set drupal or my OVH host?